# Tablet PC development

Tags: windows, tablet

What do I need to develop for a Windows Tablet PC on a regular PC? Do I need an emulator and SDK (I am coming from Android development), or is it just a special mode of standard Windows 7?
Can anyone point me to some good resources about it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 (and Vista) have the Tablet PC libraries in all Premium editions and up.  You may need to go to *Programs and Features* and install the Windows feature *Tablet PC Optional Components* if it had been removed by you, your OEM, etc.

At that point you'll have the libraries you need to develop in C++, a .Net language, VB6, or another language that can use COM and ActiveX.

However you'll want the Tablet PC SDK as well, and for a Win XP system (that isn't Tablet Edition) you'll need it for the libraries too.  Version "1.7 Update" seems to be the newest as I write this.  There is also a TPCSDK 1.7 Supplement.  Check Microsoft Downloads for these.

In many cases you can dvelop on a desktop system, making sure to set UseMouseForInput = True or the equivalent depending on what controls and classes you're using.  You can also use outboard digitizer pads.

But a target platform for testing is very useful, such as either a pen/stylus touchscreen digitizer or even a capacitive multitouch screen (not the best choice, poor drawing resolution since they're made for fingers or a "fat tip" stylus).

See [Tablet PC Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms840454.aspx)